# join two columns to one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, max

I have a table defining 'connections' and another defining 'equipment'

I have a 'source_system_name' and `'destination_system_name'` columns in connections table.
and `"system_name"` that matches these in `"equipment"` table.

The equipment can be various type:

```
1. Core 
2. Aggregation 
3. Customer.
```

I am trying to define a query to return the "type" for both the source and destinations fields from equipment table.

connection table is like:

```
id | Source Name | Source port | Destination Name | Destination Port | etc...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
4    Device_core1  1/1           Device_agg3        3/4
```

Equipment table is like:

```
id | Equip_name   | Equip type | etc....
------------------------------------------
3    Device_core1 | Core
7    Device_agg3  | Aggregation
```

I am trying to get the results returned like:

```
id | Source Name |Source port|Source type|Destination Name|Destination Port|Destination type|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Device_core1  1/1         Core        Device_agg3      3/4              Aggregation
```

The query I'm trying to use is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM connections 
LEFT JOIN equipment on connections.system_name_source=equipment.system_name 
OR connections.system_name_dest=equipment.system_name;
```

When I do this I get double records where the, `Source type` field gets overwritten by `Destination type` and vice versa.
Is there a query I can use to lookup the `equipment` table for both source and destination data? 
ie.,

```
id | Source Name |Source port|Source type|Destination Name|Destination Port|Destination type|
1   Device_core1  1/1         Aggregation Device_agg3      3/4              Aggregation 
2   Device_core1  1/1         Core        Device_agg3      3/4              Core
```

Comment: You should specify fields manually and then you'll be able to set appropriate tables and aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do Self Join.. Try this query:

```
SELECT 
connections.id,
connections.Source_Name,
connections.Source_port,
src.systype SourceType,
connections.Destination_Name,
connections.Destination_Port,
tgt.systype DestinationType
FROM connections 
LEFT JOIN equipment src on connections.system_name_source=src.system_name 
LEFT JOIN equipment tgt on connections.system_name_dest=tgt.system_name
```

In the above query, I have aliased the `equipment` table twice as `src` and `tgt`.

Comment: Sorry for my newbiness. I don't understand what you are doing with: "src.Source_type" and "FROM connections conn".(what is the term for this so I can reseach? It my help to use actual table/field names.
The connections table name is:"connections" column names are"system_name_source" and "system_name_dest". The equipment table name is "equipment" and column names are "system_name" and "systype". Thanks heaps for your input

Comment: @Nigel I have updated the above query based on the column names you provided

Comment: Thanks - This works great: Of interest . I now can't use original table name when using alias but need to use one of the alias names

Comment: @Nigel Since the same `equipment` table is being referred twice, you will need to use different alias names (for example, src and stg) instead the original name

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.sourceName, c.sourcePort, 
       MAX(IF(c.sourceName = e.Equip_name, e.equipType, '')) sourceType, 
       c.destinationName, c.destinationPort, 
       MAX(IF(c.destinationName = e.Equip_name, e.equipType, '')) destinationType
FROM `connection` c
LEFT JOIN equipment e ON e.Equip_name IN (c.sourceName, c.destinationName) 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. I'm a newbie. Can you please explain what you are doing and how this works.

Comment: @Nigel I had joined connection table and equipment table with Equip_name of equipment table to source and destination name of connection table. Then fetched type based on source name and destination name

Comment: Thanks - This works great as well. I'll probably go with "Hashbrowns solution only because it is a bit easier for me to understand :)